# Simple way to count disk usage after a certain date

Tags: command-line, find, du

I am looking for a simple way to count the used space in a directory (and sub-dirs) from a certain date onward.

This could be done by creating an exclude file with `find` and parsing this to `du` with an exclude option but I am wondering if there isn't a nicer way to do this. The amount of files to be counted are several hundred thousands.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `find`, and `du` piped into `awk` should work - something like the following

```
 find -mtime -10 -type f -exec du '{}' \; | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

where you can adjust the `mtime` parameter (or use `mmin`) to suit your needs. In this example files modified up to 10 days ago are included.

Comment: A -type f should be added or else it will count both the file and the complete dir, but this works indeed and suits the purpose. It does take a lot of resources thought, where a single du will give me a total within seconds now it is crunching for several minutes.

Comment: This will not count "disk usage after a certain date" but the size of files modified after a certain date ... which isn't quit the same.

Comment: @jmetz if you have a file of say 10 GB at day zero, and then append 5 GB at day one, what are your disk usage from day zero to day two ? Your solution would say 15 GB ... I would say 5 GB. if you don't have a baseline for day zero (the "certain day") you can't calculate the disk udef from day zero to day two. I can't  guess what is eight for OP.

Comment: @jmetz isn't "count used space in a directory (and sub-dirs) from a certain date onward." about "change in disk-usage" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122810/discussion-between-jmetz-and-soren-a).

Comment: @SorenA - if you feel that the OP used misleading language in their question formulation, you can suggest an edit/improvement to the way they expressed their question. Otherwise, I suggest you create your own separate question and answer is you're interested in the question of _change_ in disk usage over time.